Local Notification not working - userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:) not getting called in foreground with C++ interop
I have a Swift/iOS application that uses storyboards and implements local notifications using UNUserNotificationCenter. The notification code works perfectly in all my other applications. However, in this particular app, I have a requirement to enable C++ / Objective-C++ under Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Language -> C++ and Objective-C Interoperability.
Issue:
When I enable the "C++ / Objective-C Interoperability" setting, the local notifications stop working. There are no errors or crashes; the notifications simply do not appear.
Steps tried:

Verified the notification settings and permissions in the app.
Ensured that the notification code works when the interoperability setting is disabled.

Environment:

Xcode Version: 15.0.1
iOS Deployment Target: 13.0
Language: Swift

What could be causing the local notifications to fail when "C++ / Objective-C Interoperability" is enabled in the build settings? Are there any specific considerations or additional configurations required to make notifications work in this scenario?
AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                print("Notification permission granted.")
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Notification permission error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    private func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }
}

MainViewController.swift
@IBAction func submitBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Testing Notification"
    content.body = "This is a test notification"
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "MainViewController", content: content, trigger: nil)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("MainViewControllerLog", "Error delivering notification: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("MainViewControllerLog", "Notification scheduled: \(content.title) - \(content.body)")
        }
    }
    
}

expectation is to receive local notification when app is in foreground

I've investigated your code and created test app switching to C++ / Objective-C Interoperability.
Problem was in original UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol method's implementation.
For Obj-C it has signature func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) you've used:
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    private func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }
}

But for C++ should be used other signature func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) which returns Int type instead of [UNNotificationPresentationOptions] in completionHandler:
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
      completionHandler(Int(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.banner.rawValue))
    } else {
      completionHandler(Int(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert.rawValue))
    }
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandler()
  }
}

Also I've added check for iOS version as .alert is deprecated from iOS 14.0.
Tested everything on device and it worked for me.
Please, do not hesitate to ask questions in comments if you have any.
